# How to use tokens in Link attributes in VariantField?

Tags: sxa

I need to have a certain field (field type `Link Field`) to have anchoring feature for that I need the `id` to be generated I was thinking if we can use `VariantField`'s `Link attributes` property to generate that as below.

I tried using `$item.Name` or `$name` in `Link attributes` in a `VariantField`

[image: VariantField - Link attributes]

Also, if anyone can guide on generating href with hash id `#id` for the same?

Please help.

// using SXA 1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on SC 9.0.2 with SXA 1.7.1

Some observations,

1. When tested this on promo component - `@(Item.ID)` works on `DataAttributes` but `$(Item.ID)` does not.
2. Both `@(Item.ID)` and `$(Item.ID)` do not work `LinkAttributes` and specifically for `Navigation` component

So I had to override `RenderVariantField` class as below,

```
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

namespace ProjectName.Foundation.Navigation.Pipelines.RenderVariantField
{
    public class RenderVariantField : Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantField
    {
        protected override string GetAttributeTokenValue(string fieldName, Item item)
        {
            if (fieldName == "Item.ID")
            {
                return item.ID.ToString();
            }
            else if (fieldName == "Item.Name")
            {
                return item.Name;
            }

            return base.GetAttributeTokenValue(fieldName, item);
        }
    }
}
```

In code above, I could have written more dynamic code to resolve all properties of Item but that was not required by me so kept it simple to just check for `Item.ID` and `Item.Name`.

Patch config as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <renderVariantField>
                <processor patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantField, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants']"
                           type="ProjectName.Foundation.Navigation.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantField, ProjectName.Foundation.Navigation" resolve="true"/>
            </renderVariantField>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Thanks @Alan Płócieniak your answer helped me but I had to write some more code to get this working.

Comment: i was trying out your solution because i have the same problem and it worked for variantFields however i need to apply the same solution for VariantSection but it didn't work out, any idea why?

Answer (score 7):

## TL;DR

Yes it is possible, use this: `@(Item.ID)`

I assume that you are using SXA renderings or if it's custom rendering its model inherits from `RenderingModelBase`

If you need an explanation, please read the rest of my answer.

## Dynamic attributes

I will describe all the possibilities that I know and will paste a screenshot with example configuration and output at the end.

#### Field - basic

If you use the following notation: `$(FIELD_NAME)`, a raw value of a field **FIELD_NAME** will be rendered (if it's not handled in a special way - see next point).

This case will be applied to Single-Line Text, Multi-Line ...

#### Field - custom "field renderers"

If you use the following notation: `$(FIELD_NAME)` and the field type is handled in a special way in the code you can expect something different than raw value.

For example, if you specify an image, a link to this image will be generated instead of the direct value from the field.

You can find a list of fields handled in a special way in class: **RenderRenderingVariantFieldProcessor.cs**

I will write what it's there in **SXA 1.7.1**

- ImageField
- FileField
- ReferenceField
- LinkField
- TextField
- MultilistField
- LookupField

#### Model - property extractor

If you use this notation: `@(PROPERTY_PATH)` you can access properties from your model (code model) used to render rendering.

Example:
Assuming that you are using the default model: **RenderingModelBase** you can write something like this:

`@(IsEdit)` - this will render bool value of the **IsEdit** property

[image]

I called it **property extractor** because you can go deeper. If you access for example **Item** property, then you can display its **ID**

## Example

Examples are the best to understand something, so here is an example configuration and output.

[image]

Comment: I have tried `$(Item.Title)` on `Link attributes` and it resolves the field value from `RenderRenderingVariantFieldProcessor.GetAttributeTokenValue(string fieldName, Item item)` but I need Item's Name or ID but this method resolves the field value for an item, how should be the solution to resolve `$(Item.ID)`?

Comment: Also as per regex for `AttributeFieldToken` in `RenderRenderingVariantFieldProcessor` class I found `@(Item.Title)` will not work

Comment: @HarshBaid I was testing it on 1.8 but I compared the code and looked like it should work on 1.7.1 as well. The answer to your question is in my answer.

Comment: I'm using SXA's `Navigation` component this doesn't work on that. Another strange thing is `NavigationController` doesn't inherit from `VariantsController` but repository and model for this are inheriting from variants based base classes or interfaces.

Comment: I also cannot access `@(Rendering.Parameters["Styles"])` from a VariantField (SXA 1.8)

Comment: @HarshBaid `NavigationController` has its own `GetModel` that's why. It wouldn't get anything from `VariantsController`. In the past, some of the renderings had to inherit from it and have their own Controller, today basic renderings like: Title, Page content could use `VariantsController` directly.
@BenSewards it's not that cool. Property extractor can access properties only via dots (example: `Item.Paths.Path`- YES, `Item.Fields["Title"]` - NO). It has nothing to do with nvelocity in the backend.