# Using Sitecore item link as token in Sxa rendering VariantSection

Tags: sxa

I'm trying to use the `Sitecore item link` as tokens in the data or link attributes as part of the `VariantSection`. I referred to this [How to use tokens in Link attributes in VariantField?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16382/how-to-use-tokens-in-link-attributes-in-variantfield) but didn't get the exact token for it.

[image]